# Group By word count fore conversion table Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I need to count how many words are in each particular category. So for example, in my case, im doing this right now to count how many words are in a particular listing.

```
@if (str_word_count($stats->description) < 250)
     0 - 249
@elseif(str_word_count($stats->description) >= 250 && str_word_count($stats->description) <= 500)
    250 - 500
@elseif(str_word_count($stats->description) >=  501 && str_word_count($stats->description) <= 750)
    500 - 750
@else
    750+
@endif
```

At the end I have a table where I need to count by each category. Like this:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center" colspan="6">Conversion Rate For Word Count</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>0 - 249 words</th>
                                <th>250 - 500 words</th>
                                <th>500 - 750 words</th>
                                <th>750 + words</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

How would I count all the listings that have 0  -249 words and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like that work for you?

PHP

```
$counts = ['0-249'=>0, '250-499'=>0, '500-749'=>0, '750+'=>0];
@if (str_word_count($stats->description) < 250)
     $counts['0-249']++;
@elseif(str_word_count($stats->description) >= 250 && str_word_count($stats->description) <= 500)
    $counts['250-499']++;
@elseif(str_word_count($stats->description) >=  501 && str_word_count($stats->description) <= 750)
    $counts['500-749']++;
@else
    $counts['750+']++;
@endif
```

HTML

```
                <table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center" colspan="6">Conversion Rate For Word Count</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>0 - 249 words</th>
                            <th>250 - 499 words</th>
                            <th>500 - 749 words</th>
                            <th>750 + words</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $counts['0-249']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $counts['250-499']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $counts['500-749']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $counts['750+']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```